# Insert multiple rows without calling model save inside loop

Tags: magento2, model, save

Following code is working fine.

```
$data = $this->_customDataSave->create();
$data->setUsername($this->getUsername());
$data->setFullname($this->getFullname());
$data->setEmail($this->getEmail());
$data->save();
```

But I need to execute this piece of code in the loop to insert multiple of rows of data.
I don't want to call save inside loop.
How can I do that without calling save inside loop?

Comment: Try this: 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('mytest');
$connection->insertMultiple($tableName, $rowsData);

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `insertMultiple` function of class `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection`

```
protected $connection;

protected $resource;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    ...
) {
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function insertMultiple($table, $data)
{
    try {
        $tableName = $this->resource->getTableName($table);
        return $this->connection->insertMultiple($tableName, $data);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       //Error
    }
}
```

Now you can use `insertMultiple()` function like

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    $bulkInsert[] = [
        'user_name' => $record['user_name'],
        'email' => $record['email']
    ];
}

$this->insertMultiple('my_table', $bulkInsert);
```

Comment: How can we update here if the record is exist?

Comment: @jafarpinjar I just deep into the code and found that insertArray() function use  REPLACE strategy. Please check with passing PRIMARY KEY in bulk insert. Please check this for more: \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::insertArray

Comment: it's working fine. but if run again it will insert duplicate records. how to check and insert.