# How can I insert multiple row at once without for loop using collection in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, collection, save

I want insert multiple record without for loop in Magento 2
my data is as follow,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [path] => whatsapp_contact/whatsapp_contact_button_settings/info_button_click
            [field_data] => Click one of our representatives below to chat on WhatsAppFrom Admin
            [form_key] => Rcs1nNj5OzkBwuK4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [path] => whatsapp_contact/whatsapp_contact_button_settings/info_button_click
            [field_data] => 
            [form_key] => Rcs1nNj5OzkBwuK4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [path] => whatsapp_contact/whatsapp_contact_button_settings/info_button_click
            [field_data] => 
            [form_key] => Rcs1nNj5OzkBwuK4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [path] => whatsapp_contact/whatsapp_contact_button_settings/info_button_click
            [field_data] => 
            [form_key] => Rcs1nNj5OzkBwuK4
        )

)
```

need to insert at once without for loop using collection

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220011/36463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insertMultiple` function of class `Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection`

```
protected $connection;

protected $resource;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    ...
) {
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $this->resource = $resource;
}

public function insertMultiple($table, $data)
{
    try {
        $tableName = $this->resource->getTableName($table);
        return $this->connection->insertMultiple($tableName, $data);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       //Error
    }
}
```

Now you can use `insertMultiple()` function like

```
foreach($records as $record) {
    $bulkInsert[] = [
        'user_name' => $record['user_name'],
        'email' => $record['email']
    ];
}

$this->insertMultiple('my_table', $bulkInsert);
```